# writing to file using cat and write in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to write the output of cat into a file in R like this:

```
write(cat(as.character(i),"\n"),file="output.txt",append=TRUE)
```

However, it is not writing anything.

Note- `cat(as.character(i),"\n"` has a non-null output.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use fully qualified path (like `file="c:\\output.txt"` in windows or `file="/tmp/output.txt"` on linux. I'm pretty sure the file is written, but not where you're looking for.

Comment: You don't need `write` and `cat`, you can just use `cat` alone

Comment: And side note, why not giving the file output directly to the `cat` command as `write` is a wrapper to `cat` ?

Comment: Try `cat(as.character(i), sep = "\n", file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)`

Answer (score 12):

Why are you using `cat` inside `write`?

`write` is a wrapper for `cat`, so you could use either `write` or `cat` for this, but not both:

```
write(as.character(i), file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
```

or

```
cat(as.character(i), sep = "\n", file = "output.txt", append = TRUE)
```